# How can I handle both kinds of SearchView in my library?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview, android-library

## Situation

I'm building a library which will facilitate the construction of Instant Search interfaces on Android.
This library manipulates [`SearchViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) and other UI elements to link them together and handles their state.

Consequently, I have some methods taking `SearchView` objects as parameters, and I'm faced with a dilemma: either I use `android.widget.SearchView` or `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, but I cannot accept *both* **AppCompat
's SearchView** and the **standard SearchView**.

Currently, I handle this problem by overloading the public methods of my library to accept both `SearchView` classes, and manipulating internally a wrapper class which holds a reference to an instance of each kind of `SearchView`, can be initialized with any and which forwards each method call to the actual `SearchView`:

```
public class SearchViewFacade {
    private SearchView searchView;
    private android.support.v7.widget.SearchView supportView;

    public SearchViewFacade(SearchView searchView) {
        this.searchView = searchView;
    }

    public SearchViewFacade(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView) {
        supportView = searchView;
    }

    public void setQuery(CharSequence query, boolean submit) {
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setQuery(query, submit);
        } else {
            supportView.setQuery(query, submit);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Question

Obviously this is not a very good solution: the need to wrap `SearchView`'s methods will be quite burdensome. This also prevents IDEs from fetching the original documentation.

I searched for public projects that solve this problem or existing questions around this topic, but couldn't find any hint at a solution.

### Is there a better way for a library to handle both standard and AppCompat's `SearchView`?

Comment: what stops you from using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` only?

Comment: Some users of my library that don't care about supporting older devices would be forced to use AppCompat's `SearchView`, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: so give them two different libs ;-)

Comment: That's an option, but I would rather avoid the user the burden & confusion that can come from having two versions if there is an alternative :)